# I have a problem in Remastersys

Tags: custom-distributions, remastersys

While im testing custom iso resulted by remastersys the following message appears for all choices:

> could not find ramdisk image /casper/initrd.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **relinux** it's much better than **Remastersys**